# How can I reload cogs in pycord? Any code changes doesn't applied

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I'm using pycord 2.4.1 and python 3.11.1.
When I reload extension in pycord, It says it was reloaded but any changes aren't applied.
When I add commands, It doesn't appeared. When I changed some codes, It doesn't applied and still work like before I change. Only variables were changed, Codes were never changed.
When I want to apply changes, I should shut down and restart python. I want to reload by using commands. How can I do?

This is my code.
main.py

```
# coding: utf-8
import discord
import os
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timezone as tz
from datetime import timedelta as td
from SkyLib import tui
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)
hanul_ver = "0.0 rev 1 build 1 @ 20230704"
guild_ids = [#deleted due to privacy]
bot.hanul_ver = hanul_ver


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global LoadedTime
    LoadedTime = str(dt.now(tz(td(hours=9))).strftime("%Y년 %m월 %d일 %H시 %M분 %S.%f"))[:-3]+"초"
    bot.LoadedTime = LoadedTime
    print('┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐')
    print('│'+tui.fixedWidth(f'{bot.user.name}(#{bot.user.id})으로 로그인되었습니다.', 70, 1)+'│')
    print('│'+tui.fixedWidth(f'봇이 시작된 시각 : {LoadedTime}', 70, 1)+'│')
    print('└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘')
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(name='구름IDE에서 동작'))


@bot.slash_command(name="reload", guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def reload_extension(ctx):
    isowner = await bot.is_owner(ctx.author)
    if isowner:
        for filename in os.listdir("Cogs"):
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                try:
                    bot.reload_extension(f"Cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
                except discord.ExtensionNotFound:
                    channel = self.bot.get_channel(#deleted due to privacy)
                    await channel.send(f":x: '{filename[:-3]}' Can't find file")
                except discord.ExtensionNotLoaded:
                    channel = self.bot.get_channel(#deleted due to privacy)
                    await channel.send(f":x: '{filename[:-3]}' File doesn't load properly")
                except (discord.NoEntryPointError, discord.ExtensionFailed):
                    channel = self.bot.get_channel(#deleted due to privacy)
                    await channel.send(f":x: '{filename[:-3]}' Error while loadin gfile")
                else:
                    print(f'{filename[:-3]} File reloaded completed')
        await ctx.respond(f"Reload of Hanulbot is completed. new package version : {bot.repack_no}")
    else:
        await ctx.respond('This command can use only Sorame Hato.')
        

def load_extensions():
    for filename in os.listdir('Cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            bot.load_extension('Cogs.{}'.format(filename[:-3]))

load_extensions()

with open('token.txt','r') as token:
    bot.run(token.readline())
```

Cogs\info.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime as dt
global guild_ids
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
from main import guild_ids

class errorHandling(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.bot.repack_no = '0.0 rev 0 pack 2 @ 20230710'

    @commands.slash_command(name='version_check',guild_ids=guild_ids,description='temp command for checking reload')
    async def checkVer(self, ctx):
        await ctx.respond(f'package version : {self.bot.repack_no}, version no : 2')    

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(errorHandling(bot))
```

[Discord Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHydG.png)

```
[12:35 AM] BOT 하늘봇: package version : 0.0 rev 0 pack 1 @ 20230710, version no : 1
[12:35 AM] BOT 하늘봇: Reload of Hanulbot is completed. New package version : 0.0 rev 0 pack 2 @ 20230710
[12:35 AM] BOT 하늘봇: package version : 0.0 rev 0 pack 2 @ 20230710, version no : 1
```

I changed code of version check command from `await ctx.respond(f'package version : {self.bot.repack_no}, version no : 1')` to `await ctx.respond(f'package version : {self.bot.repack_no}, version no : 2')`. When I reloaded extensions, self.bot.repack_no variable was changed, but this code isn't applied and my bot still says `version no : 1`.
I searched google and stackoverflow, but there aren't any people who are suffering same problem with me, and I don't know what should I do. I saw API Document, I think there aren't any other way to reload cogs.
I also tried using unload_extensions() and load_extensions(), but it was same.